# Issues with Positioning box contents inside jquery Slider

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to modify a jquery plugin (Infinite Carousel) to present some boxes instead of a plain image content. Here is the [Demo](http://www.geoca.com/Sample/index.html)

I m not sure if this is more styling or scripting issue but I am encountering with tow problems as:
1 - Contents of The Second round (First Click to Right) Doesn't fit inside the wrapper
2 - There are some unknown dots ... after the Twelve and before the first item(in First click to left or Second Click to Right)
Can u please take look at following [Demo](http://www.geoca.com/Sample/index.html)  and let me know how I can fix them?
Thanks for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have elements in the carousel that are empty,

```
...
<li class="empty"></li>
```

with css:

```
ul.gallery li {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

If you override the border styles for empty elements the dots will disappear.

As for the scrolling issues, you are not calculating the length of the scroll correctly, 
the width of your viewport does not match the width you are scrolling, rethink this line,

```
left = singleWidth * dir * visible * n;
```

That is incorrect

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for comment but honestly I am totally confused here! Can you please let me know where did get the "li class="empty" " ? should I create that class? thanks for the second part and I am going to work on it but I realy appreciate if you kindly let me know what exactly you mean by first part? As far as I know I can not see any empty element in carousel!

Comment: @Behseini Your linked page, if you view the source code with any debugger, the list of carousel items have some empty li's in it with `class="empty"`. Your js inserts it `$slider.append(repeat('<li class="empty" />', visible - ($items.length % visible)));`

Comment: Ok,as I said I am trying to modify the code , However ,Thanks to u, i understand why it was happening! but I still do not know what was it suppose to do?! for the second part , should I modify the n ?